# How to pass none english letters to Json

Tags: c#, json, xml, xamarin, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app for Android & iOS

I'm trying to figure out how to pass none english letters to Json file.

My language is Swedish and whenever I use characters like (Å, Ä, Ö) the app crashes.

So how do I fix this please ?

DrawerViewModel.cs

```
class DrawerViewModel : BaseViewModel {
     ...

     public static DrawerViewModel BindingContext => 
        drawerViewModel = PopulateData<DrawerViewModel>("drawer.json");

     ...

     private static T PopulateData<T>(string fileName)
    {
        var file = "CykelStaden.Data." + fileName;

        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        T data;

        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            data = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }

        return data;
    }
     
}
```

drawer.json

```
{
    "itemList": [
     {
         "itemIcon": "\ue729",
         "itemName": "Länd"
      },
      {
          "itemIcon": "\ue72c",
          "itemName": "Höjd"
      },
      {
          "itemIcon": "\ue733",
          "itemName": "Mått"
      },
      {
          "itemIcon": "\ue72b",
          "itemName": "Inställningar"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How does it crash?  Can you produce a [mcve]?  If everything is unicode you should be fine.  Check your encodings.

Comment: What encoding do you use for the input file?

Comment: Which specific line causes the crash?  What is the exception?  What encoding do you use?  Have you tried using Newtonsoft instead of the Microsoft serializer?

Comment: Are you talking about the file name or the file content? If it is the latter make sure that the file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I have added the drawer.json file, and I actually do not know how to check the encoding of my app.

Comment: Don't use that old 'DataContractJsonSerializer' Microsoft recommends using `System.Text.Json` namespace.

Comment: What do you mean don't use --> "Don't use that old 'DataContractJsonSerializer' Microsoft recommends using System.Text.Json namespace."

Answer (score 1):

The json parser crashes, because the json data is not encoded correctly. The special caracters (`ä`, `ö`, `å`) have to be encoded with the same `\u` syntax.

Using this should work:

```json
{
  "itemList": [
    {
      "itemIcon": "\uE729",
      "itemName": "L\u00E4nd"
    },
    {
      "itemIcon": "\uE72C",
      "itemName": "H\u00F6jd"
    },
    {
      "itemIcon": "\uE733",
      "itemName": "M\u00E5tt"
    },
    {
      "itemIcon": "\uE72B",
      "itemName": "Inst\u00E4llningar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How did you know how to change these special characters like this?

Comment: I am from Germany, so i know the trouble. I wrote a simple console application for myself that transforms the data, but you can look up the values in any unicode table. Its the hex value of the character padded to length 4 with leading zeros.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity I found another Solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding using the [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-5.0):

```
public class DrawerItem
{
    [JsonPropertyName("itemIcon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("itemName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DrawerItemList
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        // This Encoder allows to parse Unicode Symbols without \uXXXX escaping
        Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All)
    };

    [JsonPropertyName("itemList")]
    public IEnumerable<DrawerItem> DrawerItems { get; set; }

    public static DrawerItemList LoadFromEmbeddedJsonFile(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return LoadFromEmbeddedJsonFileAsync(cancellationToken).Result;
    }

    public static async Task<DrawerItemList> LoadFromEmbeddedJsonFileAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        const string ManifestResourceName = "CykelStaden.Data.drawer.json";

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ManifestResourceName))
        {
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<DrawerItemList>(stream, _serializerOptions, cancellationToken); 
        }
    }
}
```

### Make it work with Xamarin/`netstandard2.0`/`netstandard2.1`

**IMPORTANT:** To make this work in a Xamarin Project to have to reference the `System.Text.Json` Nuget Package. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json).

You can do this with the .NET CLI (Command Line Interface):

```
dotnet add package System.Text.Json
```

The Reason for this is that the `System.Text.Json` API's were first shipped with .NET Core 3 (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) and are therefore not included in the `netstandard2.0` or `netstandard2.1` framework, which existed before .NET Core 3.

### How can I see that I am targeting `netstandard2.0` or `netstandard2.1`?

When you look into the `.csproj` File you should see a line like this:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

or

```xml
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

If `<TargetFramework>` contains another value you most likely don't have to add the `System.Text.Json` Nuget Package.

Comment: Net getting this code to work

Comment: maybe because i used .net5 as target framework :/

Comment: I think I'm also using that one

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The code is just giving me red under line on almost every line. Adding imports are not helping much either

Comment: I could put my code on Github if you would like to take a close look at it

Comment: That would be helpful, but to manage expectations i have not much experience with Xamarin Forms and because of my my schedule i could only take a look by tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238867/discussion-between-dominik-viererbe-and-jaser).

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonConvert instead,I test it on my side and it works fine.
The code is from the sample I create under this question:[Write a Text File (or PDF File) from Json in Xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702270/write-a-text-file-or-pdf-file-from-json-in-xamarin-forms/68720980#68720980)

code like:

```
 private void saveload_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myfile=Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory,"myjson.txt");
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(myfile));
}
```